# An interesting problem: Are $\mu$ and $\nu$ equal?

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Recently, I met an interesting question. That is, if $\mu$ and $\nu$ are two probability measure defined on $X$ ($\mu(X)=\nu(X)=1$), satisfying $$\mu(A)=\nu(A), \quad or \quad \mu(A)+\nu(A)=1, \forall A\subseteq X.$$ Is there a mild condition, under which $\mu=\nu$?

If there is no constraint on $\mu$ and $v$, I have a counterexample, i.e., let $\mu=\frac{1}{3}\delta_{x}+\frac{2}{3}\delta_y$, and  $\nu=\frac{2}{3}\delta_x+\frac{1}{3}\delta_y$, then $\mu$ and $\nu$ satisfy the above condition, but clearly, $\mu\neq \nu$.

That is the only counterexample I can think of. I believe there exist very mild condition under which $\mu$ and $\nu$ are equal. But I cannot identify it. I will also appreciate it if you can provide other counterexamples, which may help me.

Comment: Well, $\mu$ and $\nu$ being [nonatomic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_(measure_theory)#Non-atomic_measures) would do the trick.

Comment: Yes, you are right. If $\mu$ and $\nu$ are nonatomic, we can prove the equality. But I think this condition is a little strong. I think there should exist milder conditions